# Submitting a form with onclick and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onclick, onsubmit

I'm trying to setup a 'Click to Chat' system for my company. It requires a form which captures some information from the user. When you submit the form, it's supposed to open a new window using the script in the .js file.

I tried to add some validation, which resulted in both an onclick, and an onsubmit function. When the form is subitted without the validation in place, it opens a new window using the `BG.startChatWithIssueForm(this.form, true);` function. But, For some reason, when I include the onsubmit for validation, the onclick ignores it completely.

I've tried nesting the `BG.startChatWithIssueForm(this.form, true);` function in different spots in the `formValidator()` function, but it still results in a file download prompt instead of opening a new window.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been researching this for weeks, and can't seem to come up with anything. Javascript is definitely not my forte, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

See the code below:

JS:

```
function Bomgar() {
    var _host = "";
    var _protoRe = /^(http|https):\/\//;
    
    /* private */
    function _createURL(params, forPopup) {
        var qStr = "";
        for (var k in params) {
           qStr += "&"+encodeURIComponent(k)+"="+encodeURIComponent(params[k]);
        }
        qStr = "popup="+(forPopup ? "1" : "0") + "&c2cjs=1" + qStr;

        return _host+"api/start_session.ns?"+qStr;
    };

    function _openWindow(params) {
        return window.open(_createURL(params, true), 'clickToChat', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,scrollbars=no');
    };

    function _redirectWindow(params) {
        window.location.href = _createURL(params, false);
    };

    function _startChat(params, doFull) {
        var w = _openWindow(params);
        if (w && !w.closed) { return; }
        else if (doFull) { _redirectWindow(params); return; }
    };
           
    function _startChatWithSurveyValues(surveyValues, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        surveyValues.issue_menu = '1';
        _startChat(surveyValues, fallbackToFullWindow);
    };

    /* public */

   // Set the public site hostname that click to chat should be started on.
   this.setSite = function(siteHostname) {
        if (!_protoRe.test(siteHostname)) { siteHostname = "http://"+siteHostname; }
        if (siteHostname[siteHostname.length-1] != '/') { siteHostname += '/'; }
        _host = siteHostname;
    };

    // Start a click to chat session using a session key, optionally falling back to a full browser window redirect if the popup window fails to open due to popup blockers.
    this.startChatWithSessionKey = function(sessionKey, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        var p = {short_key: sessionKey};
        _startChat(p, fallbackToFullWindow);
    };
   
    // Start a click to chat session using a session key and external key, optionally falling back to a full browser window redirect if the popup window fails to open due to popup blockers.
    this.startChatWithSessionKeyAndExternalKey = function(sessionKey, externalKey, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        var p = {short_key: sessionKey, external_key: externalKey};
        _startChat(p, fallbackToFullWindow);
    };
   
    // Start a click to chat session using just an issue id and no other front end survey fields.
    this.startChatWithIssueId = function(issueId, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        _startChatWithSurveyValues({id: issueId}, fallbackToFullWindow);
    };

    // Start a click to chat session by passing the entire front end survey form element.
    // This will submit all non-button input element values on the form.
    // Any unexpected survey field names will be ignored.
    this.startChatWithIssueForm = function(formElement, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        var params = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < formElement.elements.length; i++) {
            var e = formElement.elements[i];
            if (e.name && e.value && e.type && e.type != 'button' && e.type != 'submit') {
                params[e.name] = e.value;
            }
        }
        formElement = undefined;
        params.issue_menu = '1';
        _startChat(params, fallbackToFullWindow);
        return false;
    };

    // Start a session with a representative id and name.
    this.startChatWithRepIdName = function(repId, repName, fallbackToFullWindow) {
        var p = {id: repId, name: repName};
        _startChat(p, fallbackToFullWindow);
    };

    return this;
}
var BG = Bomgar();
```

### HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://***.******.com/api/clicktochat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
BG.setSite("https://***.******.com");
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function formValidator(){
    // Make quick references to our fields
    var issueid = document.getElementById('issueid');
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var userid = document.getElementById('userid');
    var issuedesc = document.getElementById('issuedesc');
   
    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form

    if(madeSelection(issueid, "Please choose an issue"))
        {

        if(notEmpty(username, "Please enter your name"))
            {

            if(isAlphanumeric(username, "Numbers and Letters Only for name"))
                {

                if(notEmpty(userid, "Please enter your user ID"))
                    {

                    if(isAlphanumeric(userid, "Numbers and Letters Only for user ID"))
                        {

                        if(notEmpty(issuedesc, "Please type a description of your problem"))
                            {  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //check to make sure user selected their issue
    function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg){
        if(elem.selectedIndex == 0 ){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //check to make sure user entered something in the particular field
    function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
        if(elem.value.length == 0){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //check to make sure user only entered numeric characters
    function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    //check to make sure user only entered alpha characters
    function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    //check to make sure user entered only alpha or numeric characters
    function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Disable "Enter" key in Form script- By Nurul Fadilah(nurul@REMOVETHISvolmedia.com)
* This notice must stay intact for use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/
               
function handleEnter (field, event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
           if (field == field.form.elements[i])
               break;
        i = (i + 1) % field.form.elements.length;
        field.form.elements[i].focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
} 
</script>
 
 
<form action="https://***.******.com/api/start_session.ns" onsubmit="return formValidator();"  method="get">
What issue are you having?
<select onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" id="issueid" name="id">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1">I need help getting started</option>
<option value="2">I am receiving an error</option>
</select>
<br />
Your First and Last Name: <input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="text" id="username" name="customer_name" /><br />
Your User ID (ABC1234): <input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="text" id="userid" name="customer_id" /><br />
Describe Your Issue: <textarea onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" id="issuedesc" name="customer_desc"></textarea><br />
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="hidden" name="issue_menu" value="1" />
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="BG.startChatWithIssueForm(this.form, true); return false;" />
<br>
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="button" name="reset_form" value="Clear" onclick="this.form.reset();">
 
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Fixed code indention. That's my 2c, let someone else answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the submit button with a regular button, doing the validation in the onClick handler, and then submitting the form from within the onClick handler?

Edit: e.g. replace

```
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="BG.startChatWithIssueForm(this.form, true); return false;" />
```

with

```
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="BG.handleSubmit(this.form, true);" />
```

Then maybe use a Javascript function like this (I'm not sure exactly what order you want these things to happen in):

```
BG.handleSubmit = function(formElement, fallBackToFullWindow) {
    if (!formValidator())
        return;
    BG.startChatWithIssueForm(formElement, fallBackToFullWindow);
    formElement.submit();
    return false;
}
```

Edit: Your validation function should probably return false if it finds something invalid.

```
function formValidator(){
    // Make quick references to our fields
    var issueid = document.getElementById('issueid');
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var userid = document.getElementById('userid');
    var issuedesc = document.getElementById('issuedesc');

    var valid = true;

    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form

    if(!madeSelection(issueid, "Please choose an issue"))
        valid = false;

    if(!notEmpty(username, "Please enter your name"))
        valid = false;

    if(!isAlphanumeric(username, "Numbers and Letters Only for name"))
        valid = false;

    if(!notEmpty(userid, "Please enter your user ID"))
        valid = false;

    if(!isAlphanumeric(userid, "Numbers and Letters Only for user ID"))
        valid = false;

    if(!notEmpty(issuedesc, "Please type a description of your problem"))
        valid = false;

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example? I don't think I've tried that yet.

Comment: It's really close. It actually opens the BG.startChatWithIssueForm function correctly now, but it still runs whether the form validates or not. Any idea on how to make that conditional on validation?

Comment: If you want to only alert the user to one invalid field per form submission, you can change those `valid = false;` lines to `return false;` and change `return valid;` at the end to `return true;`

Comment: That took care of it! Thank you so much for your help!